# Is the language name case sensitive for syntax highlighting?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, capitalization

I often use the syntax-highlighting feature of Stack Exchange in order to make my code easier to read.

````
```lang-python
for k in range(0, 10):
    print(k)
```
````

```python
for k in range(0, 10):
    print(k)
```

There are many different ways to capitalize a string such as `lang-python`:

- `Lang-Python`
- `LANG-Python`
- `lang-PYTHON`

Is the language tag case sensitive for syntax highlighting? I often mistype it and write something like "lang-Pythn" but no error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tl;dr `lang-` must be lowercase, capitalization on the language name can be anything

---

Let's try it out [in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381439/1081494):

> #### All lowercase:
>
> ````
> ```lang-python
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
> ````
>
> ```python
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
>
> #### All caps:
>
> ````
> ```LANG-PYTHON
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
> ````
>
> ```
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
>
> #### Language name all caps:
>
> ````
> ```lang-PYTHON
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
> ````
>
> ```PYTHON
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
>
> #### All mixed caps:
>
> ````
> ```LaNg-PyThOn
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
> ````
>
> ```
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
>
> #### Language name mixed caps:
>
> ````
> ```lang-PyThOn
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```
> ````
>
> ```PyThOn
> for i in range(10):
>     if i % 2:
>         print(i)
> ```

Comment: Note that the `lang-` part is not required.